# Rails - How do I prevent Users from creating duplicates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Each user can have two aliases, but each alias must have a unique name. For example:

User1: Bob, Ron

User2: Bob

If User2 were to create another alias, how do I prevent them from naming it Bob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an easy one, you can validate the scoped uniqueness, i.e:

```
class Alias < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :alias_name, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id, case_sensitive: false }

  # existing code
end
```

This prevents the creation (or update) of an alias with the same name, which belong to the same user. The `case_sensitive` attribute makes it more strict, i.e `bob, Bob, bOb, boB, BOb, bOB, BOB` are considered to be the same.

You can find more about this in the rails' [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)